# MVVM Light Toolkit sample with RibbonControlsLibrary

Tags: ribbon, mvvm-light

I've just started playing the "MVVM Light Toolkit" and I'm wondering how can I merge RibbonCommand and RelayCommand
Is there any sample that mix MVVM Light Toolkit and RibbonControlsLibrary?

Many thanks
Claudio

Comment: I found this sample http://blogs.msdn.com/jaimer/archive/2009/02/10/m-v-vm-training-day-sample-application-and-decks.aspx but unfortunately is not build on top of MVVM Light Toolkit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my issue switching to http://fluent.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know the ribboncommand in the ribboncontrolslibrary isn't yet in its final version.

and I supopse having read, its still going to see some changes before getting production ready.

So I wouldnt encourage other peers to use it yet, as it was said to be published for year(s) now!

*I currently use it in a pre realase app for a customer, but as there are still no news around microsofts "official" wpf ribbon, i will have to switch to the fluent ribbon sooner or later..*